# Using new operator and TypeError: Cannot read property 'event' of undefined

Tags: contract-deployment, events, remix

Here's the code:

[image]

1. I compile these two contracts together and deploy **Bar** contract. After deploying it I have a contract account address where it has been deployed on the blockchain:

   **0x692a70d2e424a56d2c6c27aa97d1a86395877b3a**
2. Then I call **Bar.createFoo()** and get a new contract account address where the newly created contract **Foo** has just been deployed:

   **0xfcca7851eb308c57543421141f6fefbd1f4a2bef**

---

**My first question is:**

What is stored in the variable *whatAmI*? Is it the address of **Bar** or is it the address of my account(externally owned account) that called **Bar.createFoo()**?

---

**My second question is:**

I've added some means to log the **whatAmI** variable here:
[image]

Compiler throws an error: **TypeError: Cannot read property 'event' of undefined**

**What am I doing wrong here?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For Q1.

`whatAmI` will have the address of whatever invokes the constructor `Foo()`.  Since it was invoked by `Bar` (`createFoo`), `whatAmi` will have the address of `Bar`.

(But an external account can deploy `Foo` and in this case, `whatAmI` would be the address of the external account.  In Solidity Browser, just click on Create for Foo few times and you should see the event.)

---

For Q2.  You are not doing anything wrong to cause

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'event' of undefined

since it is a known open issue at https://github.com/ethereum/browser-solidity/issues/115

You should be fine with other uses of events.